# Missing ICC Data in ghostscript

Tags: ghostscript

For some documents that I need to convert into images (jpeg) through the (templated) command `gs -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=jpeg -dBATCH -r133 -sOutputFile=/my/path/%d.jpg file`, sometimes I get the following error :

```
./base/gdevp14.c:3632: pdf14_update_device_color_procs_push_c(): Missing ICC data
```

the process then launches a signal 11 (which is a segfault I believe). I'm using Ghostscript 9.05 on the machines where this crashes, but on another machine equipped with Ghostscript 9.10, it runs just fine, for (exactly) the same document.

I thought that I could be missing something, but what could it be ?

thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By [overriding the ICC settings](http://ghostscript.com/doc/9.05/Use.htm#ICC_color_parameters), it seems that it is doing fine : `gs -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=jpeg -dOverrideICC -dBATCH -r133 -sOutputFile=/my/path/%d.jpg file`.

A PDF that was failing, once exported to a new PDF worked just fine, so I guess there was something amiss in the original PDF, that ghostscript didn't like very much. Overriding the ICC settings with the default ones on the current machine seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Update to something a little more recent. The current version is 9.16. If you continue to experience problems then file a bug report. I would guess that your bug has been fixed somewhere between 9.05 and 9.10.....